# Apparmor is not functioning

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, live-usb, security, apparmor

When I check the status of Apparmor, I get this:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

What is wrong?

I have already downloaded/installed a profile, so that's not it.

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 on HP 2000-2b09WM Notebook PC, using a live-usb.

Could it be because I am using the live-usb?

Thank you.

RCline7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparmor that runs normally will show a number of loaded profiles. However, this is applicable only when Xubuntu has been installed to the local machine.

> Could it be because I am using the live-usb?

So the short answer is, yes.

And it is not just Live USB, but also applies to Live CD/DVD regardless of the Xubuntu releases (I have confirmed myself using Xubuntu 12.04/14.04 on both live and local sessions).

The `apparmor-profiles` package isn't included on default installation of Xubuntu. Even so, running `sudo apparmor_status` by default will show more than 10 profiles loaded for evince, NetworkManager, lightdm, etc.

There are known exceptions, such as Apparmor is disabled by default for Firefox. Someone has asked [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76412/why-do-i-have-to-enable-the-apparmor-profile-for-firefox-why-isnt-it-on-by-d) already.

Finally, you may wonder why Apparmor profiles aren't loaded on live sessions?

Apparently, Apparmor doesn't work on stacked filesystem i.e. Live CD. And this has been [reported as bug since Karmic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/131976) and likely remain unfixed to this date.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Xubuntu 14.04LTS on my HP 2000-2b09WM Notebook PC. Apparmor works on the installation, therefore, I know that the problem was the fact that I was running from a live-usb.

clearkimura was right-on, thank you.

RCline7